# Identify peaks without a priori knowledge of curve shape?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, max, min, gaussian

I have a dataset with a profile that change over time. It seems to always be roughly Gaussian in shape, but the way the Gaussian "points" (whether the Gaussian rises then falls, or falls then rises) changes over time. Each signal is not a pure Gaussian, but has noise...I'm using a Gaussian here for illustration. Two sample curves can be generated using the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norminvgauss 

numargs = norminvgauss.numargs  
a, b = 20.32, 5.18
rv = norminvgauss(a, b)  
dist_1 = np.linspace(0, np.minimum(rv.dist.b, 2))
a2, b2 = 10.32, 10.18
rv2 = norminvgauss(a2,b2)
dist_2 = np.linspace(0, np.minimum(rv2.dist.b, 15))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(rv.pdf(dist_1))
plt.plot(-rv.pdf(dist_2),'--r')
plt.show()
```

which produces these signals: [image]

Without *a priori* knowledge of which way the Gaussian points, how can I always determine the main extrema index and value (e.g., the location and magnitude of the maximum point of the cyan plot, and the minimum point of the red dashed plot)?

Comment: Solve for the root of the first-order partial of [norminvgauss](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norminvgauss.html) with respect to x. This is nasty because there's a Bessel in the mix. You're probably best off to do it numerically.

Comment: But the maximum of the cyan (Gaussian) is trivially located at its mean.

Comment: Surely `plt.plot(-rv.pdf(dist_2),'--r')` should be using `rv2`?

Comment: There are other oddities; like you should probably be passing in your `dist` as the plot's horizontal axis.

Comment: If your data are really just Gaussian, why call `norminvgauss`? Why not call [norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm)?

Comment: The data are not Gaussian, it was an approximation to illustrate the problem.  The real data are much more noisy and jump all over the place. However, I've used the FinDiff package to look at numerical derivatives of the data.